# The field "program.endgame" is assigned but its value is never used

Tags: c#

I am making a game in c#  and I need to set up a loop to check if one of the player's score hits 6. When it does, static bool endgame would be true and the loop I used for player turns will break to display the winner. I keep getting the error "The field "program.endgame" is assigned but its value is never used" Do not know why I get it but need a fix

```
static bool endgame = false;
static void Main()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < PlayerNumber; r++)
    {// make a move for player i
        if (players[r].Score == 6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(players[r].Nick + " wins the game.");
            endgame = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the message states, you are assigning a value to endgame, but then not using endgame.  So either use it to end the game as the name applies, or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning, not an error. You are getting the warning because you never reference the endgame variable. The compiler is thinking "you could just remove this variable and your program would be exactly the same" which is true.

If you are assigning the variable for your own debugging purposes, or because you plan on using it later, feel free to ignore the warning.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I suggets to don't take the habit to ignore compilation warning: most of the time they are telling you you're doing something wrong, and maybe there is a bug in your code. here, e.g. it's saying "you are not using the value you set in this variable, are you sure it is what you wanted to do?"

Comment: Never ignore a warning if at all possible. Fix it, or disable it along with a comment explaining why the warned about code is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The part you are looking for is the following, but it's still useless, if you're not planning on using it.

```
for (int r = 0; r < Player Number && !endgame; r++)
```

**This is not an error**, but a Warning, which doesn't stopping you from Running the application, but warns you that you're declaring a variable and assigning it, but never using its value.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan to do anything with the endgame variable, you can remove it. The break will end the loop.

But if you had any code later that checks endgame, you won't get that error any more.